# Grep to match all the patterns from a file

Tags: regex, string, grep, pattern-matching

I have a set of pattern strings in a file and I want to have `grep` find lines that match all of the patterns (logical AND).

In my example I want to only find the last line containing both `1` AND `2` (that is, `12`), but what actually happens in the match is a logical OR, so all lines are returned:

test_file.txt:

```
1
2
12
```

pattern.f:

```
1
2
```

And I run this command:

```
$ grep -f pattern.f test_file.txt
1
2
12
```

Can I make `grep` do what I want in one line? I don't really want to have to write a script to read the pattern match file and loop a bunch of greps or use pipes (`grep 1 test_file.txt | grep 2`).

Comment: thanks, but I am not actually searching for 1 and 2, i just made a simple test case. I'm actually searching for strings like icache and tagram3, these will be in the patern.f file and the test_file.txt will contain lines like: 24 256 6 1 1.667       # i_cpu2_socwrap - Memory instance i_europa_top:i_europa_switched_top:i_europa_core:i_cpu2_socwrap:i_m14k_cpu.icache.tagram.tag0:str

Comment: edit your question with this data. In comments it is not easy to understand code.

Answer (score 4):

It might be better to use `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} {for (i in a) if ($1 !~ i) next; print}' patt file
12
```

This reads the patterns into the array `a[]`.

Then, when reading `file` it loops through all the patterns. If one of them does not match with the current line, it skips to the next line. If it arrives to the end of the comparison, meaning the line matches all the patterns, then it prints it.

Comment: thanks, but I am not actually searching for 1 and 2, i just made a simple test case. I'm actually searching for strings like icache and tagram3, these will be in the patern.f file and the test_file.txt will contain lines like: 24 256 6 1 1.667       # i_cpu2_socwrap - Memory instance i_europa_top:i_europa_switched_top:i_europa_core:i_cpu2_socwrap:i_m14k_cpu.icache.tagram.tag0:str

Comment: I know and hence I wrote a generic code. Only that to post the answer I used your input files to produce the output I am showing. Check it with your real data and see if it works; if not, update your question with more information that may be missing. --I see you posted a lot of code here, please do it but in the question, not here.

Comment: ok, sorry, I am not familiar with awk, I thought you were looping from 1 to 2. I'll give it a try

Comment: No problem! `$1` refers to the first field of the current line. I will add a broader explanation of the code in a while. Give a try to it and see if it works.